# How to extract image features through C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

My adviser told me to use Accord Framework for C# to extract features and patterns from images. Our project is about image analysis and comparison of tobacco leaves. Does anyone here have an idea on how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty high level stuff, but from what I've learned in my time faffing with it, I'd use the `Accord.Imaging` library to scan your pictures.  Followed by using the `Accord.Neuro` namespace to "learn" from some manual data you feed into it.

Seems your goal is to create a program that scans images quickly, gleaning only the useful data from the full image, and then checking for some particular features of the image.  I've never used the library, but it looks like it'd be possible to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Dan!  So much appreciated. But one more thing, if do you know how to post results in a form of probability? e.g. Result: 0.91 instead of Excellent?

Comment: Affraid I've never used the library, so I don't know.  But I'm surprised there isn't a simple zero to one output value on one of your end layer nodes...  All neural nets that I've seen have probabilities as their outputs.